# Determining the number of decimal numbers for a currency

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization, currency

On the iPhone:

```
Using the US locale, a currency looks like this: $1,234.56
Using the UK locale, a currency looks like this: £1,234.56
Using the German (Germany) locale, a currency looks like this: 1.234,56 €

and finally, a Japanese currency: ¥1,234
```

The Japanese currency has no decimals and this impacts my custom keyboard significantly. I'm trying to find a method in the Cocoa-touch framework which will tell me how many decimal places a specific currency has - my hard-coded value of 2 isn't doing me justice :(

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the CFNumberFormatter objects to get the information you need. Specifically you could use CFNumberFormatterGetDecimalInfoForCurrencyCode:

```
CFStringRef localeIdent = CFSTR("JPY");

int numDecimals;
double rounding;
BOOL result = CFNumberFormatterGetDecimalInfoForCurrencyCode(localeIdent, &numDecimals, &rounding);
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't programmed in Cocoa for ages, but from the documentation for NSNumberFormatter, there's a function called 'currencyDecimalSeparator' - that might at least tell you if a currency has one at all, which might be a start?

Answer (score 0):

Financial companies maintain databases of this kind of information. You might be able to buy the data or import it from an online source.

Note also: some currencies need three or four decimal places. See http://www.londonfx.co.uk/ccylist.html for examples.

Comment: The NSNumberFormatter is brilliant for this. I don't have a problem with formatting since it's all done for me by the formatter. I just can't find out how to determine how many decimal places I need to provision for. Thanks for the link - interesting stuff.

Comment: By the way, ideally, I'd like to tie the number of decimals with whatever is coded into the formatter - otherwise things could just go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the answers above didn't really solve my problem.

I ended up using the maximumFractionDigits method on NSNumberFormatter which gave me 0 for Japanese locale. Make sure you use a **NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle** for the formatter, otherwise you'll see decimal places in other formatters.

```
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSLog(@"Number of decimal places %i", [currencyFormatter maximumFractionDigits]);
```